# return data from sendAsynchronousReques

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, callback, return

Objective c: I have a serviceClass connecting to a db with `NSURLConnection` and `sendAsynchronousRequest`.

I want to be able to use this class method and return the db-data to any other classmethod requesting it.

But since the `sendAsynchronousRequest` is returning void - how can i do this?

I cant get my head around it at all atm. Blocks? But how...

Please help

atm I am creating a user object directly in this codechunk bellow:

```
[NSURLConnection
 sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
 queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
 completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *urlResponse,
                     NSData *data,
                     NSError *error) {

     if ([data length] > 0 && error == NULL){ // do success or error call with true or    false
         NSMutableData *incomingData;
         if(!incomingData) {
             incomingData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
         }
         [incomingData appendData:data];
         NSString *string = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:incomingData
                                                 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
         //incomingData = nil;

         // create dictionary from json
         NSData *jsondata = [NSData dataWithData:incomingData];
         NSMutableDictionary *userDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsondata 
                                                                                  options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                                                                                    error:NULL];
         // create user object
         User *user = [User userFromDictionary:userDictionary];
         NSLog(@"user back to object successfull!! %@", user);

     }



     }
```

Comment: are you getting data in incomingData?

Comment: yes. I get the data from the db. so far so good..

Comment: you want to access incomingData in this class itself? If that the case, then you can just create property for this and access it through out the class.

Comment: I want to be able to pass the data along so that other classes can access the data. not use it in the class itself.

Comment: you can do that as well using property of this, if this is initialised without returning from class you can send anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use property for incomingData and then use that property to pass data to other methods/class.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData * incomingData;
```

Now you can use `self.incomingData` to set value, and you need to return. You can use it in other methods, and when you need to pass this to other class, you can pass it.

Comment: but how can I return the incoming data from within the asyncronous completion handler? When I call it from another method/class it gets null since the asyncrounus still is working in the background.
Hope you understand my question.

Comment: i am not saying to return anything, you just set the data as a property, now you can pass it anywhere without returning, have you tried implementing this?